# How to store constant string in separate file in groovy script

Tags: groovy, jira

I need to place some constant string in separate file as

String MYTABLE="Customer"
String FIELD="Price"
String ......

Then how can declare those constant string in the file in order o use them in the main file ?

Ex : import Helper.MyString

and use them as MyString.MYTABLE

Thanks for help
regards

Comment: maybe better to use json file and JsonSlurper to parse it. or groovy config and ConfigSlurper to parse it?

Comment: Or you could even use a plain old properties file.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

one directory contains two files:

```
* ConstantStrings.groovy
* YourScript.groovy
```

Inside ConstantStrings.groovy

```
class ConstantStrings{
     static String MY_STRING = "some value"
}
```

Inside YourScript.groovy

```
import ConstantStrings
log.warn("MY_STRING: ${ConstantStrings.MY_STRING}") 
//should log the following: MY_STRING: some value
```

Hope this helps